# Showing input prompt in python

Tags: python, python-idle

I am using IDLE for Python on a Mac OS. I wrote the following in a .py file:

```
import math
def main():
    print "This program finds the real solution to a quadratic"
    print

    a, b, c = input("Please enter the coefficients (a, b, c): ")

    discRoot = math.sqrt(b * b-4 * a * c)
    root1 = (-b + discRoot) / (2 * a)
    root2 = (-b - discRoot) / (2 * a)

    print
    print "The solutions are: ", root1, root2

main()
```

IDLE now permanently displays:

> This program finds the real solution to a quadratic
>
> Please enter the coefficients (a, b, c):

When I enter 3 numbers (ex: 1,2,3) IDLE does nothing.  When I hit enter IDLE crashes (no crash report).

I quit and restarted but IDLE is now permanemtly displaying the above and won't respond to other files.

Comment: One problem is that you don't see an exception raised in `math.sqrt` for `1,2,3` input.

Comment: In your example, shouldn't b*b be larger than 4ac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `math` module does not support complex numbers. If you replace `import math` with `import cmath` and `math.sqrt` with `cmath.sqrt`, your script should work like a charm.

EDIT: I just read "This program finds the real solution to a quadratic". Taking into consideration that you only want real roots, you should check for negative discriminants as the Kevin has pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

There is no real solution to the equation X^2 + 2x + 3 = 0. You will get a `ValueError` when trying to take the square root of `b * b-4 * a * c`, which is negative. You should handle this error case somehow. For example, a try/except:

```
import math
def main():
    print "This program finds the real solution to a quadratic"
    print

    a, b, c = input("Please enter the coefficients (a, b, c): ")

    try:
        discRoot = math.sqrt(b * b-4 * a * c)
    except ValueError:
        print "there is no real solution."
        return
    root1 = (-b + discRoot) / (2 * a)
    root2 = (-b - discRoot) / (2 * a)

    print
    print "The solutions are: ", root1, root2

main()
```

Or you can detect that the discriminant is negative ahead of time:

```
import math
def main():
    print "This program finds the real solution to a quadratic"
    print

    a, b, c = input("Please enter the coefficients (a, b, c): ")

    discriminant = b * b-4 * a * c
    if discriminant < 0:
        print "there is no real solution."
        return
    discRoot = math.sqrt(discriminant)
    root1 = (-b + discRoot) / (2 * a)
    root2 = (-b - discRoot) / (2 * a)

    print
    print "The solutions are: ", root1, root2

main()
```

Result:

```
This program finds the real solution to a quadratic

Please enter the coefficients (a, b, c): 1,2,3
there is no real solution.
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason I see for your program failing is this:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
num = b * b - 4 * a * c

print num
```

It comes out as -8.

You normally can't have a negative number within a square root.

Like what the person above me says, import cmath should work.

http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2005-July/039461.html

```
import cmath

a, b, c = 1, 2, 3

num = cmath.sqrt(b * b - 4 * a * c)
print num
```

= 2.82842712475j